# Is there any regularizer that penalizes redundant neurons?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, regularized

I trained a network on a real-value labels (floating point numbers from 0.0 to 1.0) - several residual blocks in the beginning, and the last layers are

- fully-connected layer with 64 neurons + ELU activation,
- fully-connected layer with 16 neurons + ELU activation,
- output logistic regression layer ( 1 neuron with y = 1 / (1 + exp(-x) ).

After training, I visualised weights of the layer with 16 neurons:

1. figure rows represents weights that every single 1 of 16 neurons developed for every single 1 of 64 neurons of previous layer, indices are 0..15 and 0..63;
2. **UPD:** figure shows neurons weights correlation (Pearson);
3. **UPD:** figure shows neurons weights MAD (mean absolute difference) - this proves redundancy event better than correlation.

[image: weights of the layer before the output layer]
[image: neurons weights correlation]
[image: neurons MAD]

Now the detailed questions:

1. Can we say that there are redundant features? I see several redundant groups of neurons: `0,4`; `1,6,7 (maybe 8,11,15 too)`; `2,14`; `12,13 (maybe)` .
2. is it bad ?
3. if so, is there any regularizer, that penalizes redundant neuron weights, and makes neurons develop uncorrelated weights?

I use adam regularizer, Xavier initialization (the best of the tested), weight decay 1e-5/batch (the best of the tested), other output layers did not work as well as logistic regression (by means of precison & recall & lack of overfitting).
I use only 10 filters in each resnet blocks (which are 10, too) to address overfitting.

Comment: What's your definition of redundancy? guessing from Q3, do you mean neurons whose weights are correlated? if that's true, it's hard to figure out correlation from this heatmap.

Comment: I'm not sure but I do not think you can conclude neurons are redundant if their weights are highly correlated. I recommend you calculate correlation between your neurons using mean absolute difference(MAD) between corresponding weights for example. Once you have a clear indicator you can try training with less neurons (delete neuron with small MAD with other neuron) and see if your model performs better. It's possible this procedure could be used for regularization.

Comment: @Anton , your suggestion is good, but the procedure is either manual, or at least requires some complex coding.

Comment: @ShihabShahriarKhan I added figures to prove that weights of neurons are correlated.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Tensorflow ? if yes, is post training quantization an option ?
tensorflow.org/lite/performance/post_training_quantization

This has some similar effect to what you need but also makes other improvements.

Alternatively maybe you can also try to use Quantization-aware training
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/r1.14/tensorflow/contrib/quantize

Comment: Nope, not tensorflow but mxnet... I will check this, thanks.

Comment: You're welcome ! If you find out additional stuff please share here as well. I am also interested on the topic. Thanks !